# `else` does not show the value

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I built the code below.
Code works ok when user insert word which is inside of data variable. If user type "monda" instead of "monday" then I get error message. My "else" does not apply here.
Could you please look at that and suggest me what can I correct.
Second thing is that numbers from data they should be printed on the end in print always with same shape as in data variable but friday where is 0800 it prints me 800. How can I correct the code so it shows me 0800 in print on the end.

```
data = """
monday;1250
tuesday;1405
wednesday;1750
thursday;1100
friday;0800
saturday;1225
sunday;1355
"""
data = data.strip()
data = {day: number for day, number in [line.split(';') for line in data.split('\n')]}
day = input("Insert day: ").lower()
number = int(data[day])
temperature = 0

if day in data:
   if number >= 1400:
       temperature = number / 22.5
   elif number >= 1200 and number <=1400:
       temperature = number / 23.1
   elif number < 1200:
       temperature = number / 23.5
else:
   print("Check day and insert again, please!")

print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
```

Comment: Look at the line that is giving you the error and you'll see that it's not in your if statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If user type "monda" instead of "monday" then I get error message."

You should always check if the key exists before trying to access, or it will throw an error if it's not there. You're trying to get "monda" out of the data dictionary, which doesn't exist, to fix that, you can simply move the line `number = int(data[day])` under the if sentence.

```
if day in data:
    number = int(data[day])
    if number >= 1400:
        temperature = number / 22.5
    elif number >= 1200:   
        temperature = number / 23.1
    else:
        temperature = number / 23.5
    
    print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {:04d}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
else:
    print("Check day and insert again, please!")
```

About the 0800 and 800, you can add the ":04d" to the print statement, which will add a leading zero to the number if it doesn't have 4 digits.

Notice that you don't need to verify inside the elif statement if the number is below 1400, since the first if will do its job. Same thing with the `elif number < 1200:`, it will fall under this statement only if it failed the first and second if's.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a number, there is no difference between 800 and 0800. You must say at print time what format to use:

```
print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {:04d}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
```

Comment: Now is almost ok. So, when word is not correct then else is running proper comment but except the comment from ELSE last print line is printed as well. How to switch off that last print when ELSE condition is met?

Answer (score 1):

about the error you can change

```
number = int(data[day])
```

to

```
number = int(data.get(day, 0))
```

Comment: Now is almost ok. So, when word is not correct then else is running proper comment but except the comment from ELSE last print line is printed as well. How to switch off that last print when ELSE condition is met?

Comment: you can insert the second print inside the if section
if day in data:
   if number >= 1400:
       temperature = number / 22.5
   elif number >= 1200 and number <=1400:
       temperature = number / 23.1
   elif number < 1200:
       temperature = number / 23.5
   print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
else:
   print("Check day and insert again, please!")

Comment: It's resolved. This is exactly how I did it, thanks.

Comment: `data = data.strip()
data = {day: number for day, number in [line.split(';') for line in data.split('\n')]}
day = input("Insert day: ").lower()
while day not in data:
    day = input("Check day and insert again, please! ").lower()
number = int(data[day])
temperature = 0

if number >= 1400:
    temperature = number / 22.5
elif number >= 1200 and number <= 1400:
    temperature = number / 23.1
elif number < 1200:
    temperature = number / 23.5
print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
`

Comment: The a look on the last commet I think it's even beter for you

Answer (score 0):

First, lets simplify your example.

```
data = {
    'monday': '1250',
    'tuesday': '1405',
    'wednesday': '1750',
    'thursday': '1100',
    'friday': '0800',
    'saturday': '1225',
    'sunday': '1355'
}
day = input("Insert day: ").lower()
number = int(data[day]) # KeyError if day not in data
temperature = 0

if day in data:
    if number >= 1400:
        temperature = number / 22.5
    elif number >= 1200 and number <=1400:
        temperature = number / 23.1
    elif number < 1200:
        temperature = number / 23.5
else:
    print("Check day and insert again, please!")

print("""Data for "{}"\nNumber: {}\nTemperature {:.3f}\u2103""".format(day, number, temperature))
```

Your first problem is that if `day` is not in `data`, a `KeyError` will occur. You can resolve this by waiting to access it until you know it's in your `data` `dict`.

Your second problem is `0800` and `800` as integers are equivalent. Since python makes no assumptions about how many leading zeros to display, it just uses none. To fix this, you can just leave it as a string and use another converted variable for comparison since a string will leave your leading `0` intact.

```
data = {
    'monday': '1250',
    'tuesday': '1405',
    'wednesday': '1750',
    'thursday': '1100',
    'friday': '0800',
    'saturday': '1225',
    'sunday': '1355'
}
day = input("Insert day: ").lower()
if day in data:
    number = int(data[day])
    if number >= 1400:
        temperature = number / 22.5
    elif number >= 1200 and number <=1400:
        temperature = number / 23.1
    elif number < 1200:
        temperature = number / 23.5
    else:
        temperature = 0
    print(f'Data for "{day}"\nNumber: {data[day]}\nTemperature {temperature:.3f}\u2103')
else:
    print("Check day and insert again, please!")
```

Comment: I modified the code according to the examples above of other members and seems it's working. If I would insert the print into the internal else then I would receive only that print with else which is not correct. So I placed print in all internal if/elif and I left the last else print like on the code. Now it's working well.